# Application does not open in mobile responsive mode while running scripts using cy.viewport("anydevice")

Tags: cypress

Application does not open in mobile responsive mode while running scripts using cy.viewport("anydevice").

I am using cypress mocha, and I dont see the application in Mobile responsive view

describe('Production Test Suite', function()
{

```
it('TC02_AuthorizedLoginVerification_Mobile', function()
{
  cy.viewport('samsung-s10')
  cy.visit('https://staging.youvisit.com/tour/hanover')
  
  cy.get('div[id=registration-visitortype]').click()
  cy.get('td[item-value=prospective_student').click()
  cy.get('td[item-value=hs_student]').click()
  cy.get('div[id=registration-firstname').click()
  cy.get('input[id=firstname]').type("Test First Name")
  cy.get('div[id=registration-lastname').click()
  cy.get('input[id=lastname]').type("Test Last Name")
  cy.get('div[id=registration-email').click()
  cy.get('input[id=email]').type("Test@gmail.com")
  cy.get('select[id=enrollyear]').select("2021")
  cy.get('select[id=enrollterm]').select("Fall")
  cy.get('input[id=school]').type("Weldon Curt")
  cy.get('select[id=major]').select("Accounting")
  cy.get('select[id=gender]').select("Female")
  cy.get('div[id=registration-birthdate]').type("07/07/2000")
  cy.get('input[id=phone]').type("123456789")
  cy.get('select[id=country]').select("United States (USA)")
  cy.get('input[id=us_street]').type("Test Street") 
  cy.get('input[id=us_postal]').type("02340")
  cy.get('input[id=us_street]').click()
  cy.contains('DONE').click()
  cy.contains('Thanks for your submission!').should('be.visible')
})
```

})

Comment: Can you post your code snippet to have more clarity.

Comment: I have added the code snippet above

Comment: if you open the same url in "Chrome Emulator" , it opens in mobile responsive mode where you can either see "Continue in Browser" screen or a screen that has a "Start" button

Comment: I just tried it on my machine and I am able to open it in mobile layout with your code. `describe('Stackoverflow Question', function () {

    it('Open in S10', function () {
        cy.viewport('samsung-s10')
        cy.visit('https://staging.youvisit.com/tour/hanover')

    })
})`. https://imgur.com/Ho30laR

Comment: describe('Production Test Suite', function()
{
    
    it('Sample_GoogleLaunch', function()
    {
      cy.viewport('samsung-s10')
      cy.visit('https://www.google.com')               
})
    
  })

I tried running above code, the view looks like mobile layout but the application thats opened is still 
desktop view, it is not mobile responsive view